# Bash Script : Check if number starts with

Tags: bash

```
$var=1545334345
```

The $var is dynamic. How do I check if it starts with 15? I tried:

```
if [[ $var == 15* ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

and

```
if (( $var -eq 15* )); then
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

Neither works.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$` from the assignment.

```
var=1545334345
```

The first `if` statement you wrote is correct.

```
if [[ $var == 15* ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
fi
```